# CSIndexErrorDomain error -1005

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I am getting this error `"The operation couldn’t be completed. (CSIndexErrorDomain error -1005.)"` while running code for spotlight search on ipad.Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The CoreSpotlight is available on iOS 9 onwards.

Though your device maybe at iOS 9.x, it still may not work if it is a older device version.

From Apple docs.

> Although app search is available for iOS 9 users, the search functionality of NSUserActivity and Core Spotlight is not supported on iPhone 4s, iPad 2, iPad (3rd generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch (5th generation)."

So if you are testing on any of the above devices or simulators for the same you will get the CSIndexErrorDomain error -1005.

From Corespotlight API documentation

> CSIndexErrorCodeIndexingUnsupported =   -1005, //Indexing isn't
>   supported on this device

Comment: yes you are right. it's an older version of device .Thank you.

Comment: So basically one has to check the what device is used to know wether or not indexing is supported?

Answer (score 10):

Since the Search feature is not available on all the devices supporting iOS9 so check the following condition to know whether the device supports search

```
if ([CSSearchableIndex isIndexingAvailable])
```

and keep the methods of search under this condition.